# Can we go back to using musical instruments in synagogues when the Temple is rebuilt?

Tags: synagogue, beis-hamikdash, music

We stopped using musical instruments in the synagogue after the Temple was destroyed, as a sign of mourning.  We used them before that time (see Psalm 150).  When the Temple is rebuilt, does halacha say we can go back to using them?  For that matter, do we know if they went back to using them after the Second Temple was built?

**Very brief background:**
In ancient days, musical instruments were used in worship:  [Mishna, Arachin 2:3 - Sefaria:  https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Arakhin.2.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en]:
There are never less than two harps, nor more than six. There are never less than two flutes, nor more than twelve... And they did not play on a bronze pipe but on a reed pipe... Nor was anything but a single pipe used for the finale, because it makes a pleasant finale.

Then the Temple was destroyed, and the Talmud seemed to forbid all music, anytime: [Gittin 7a.  (Sefaria: https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.7a?lang=bi)]
They sent the following question to Mar Ukva: From where do we derive that song is forbidden in the present, following the destruction of the Temple? He scored parchment and wrote to them: “Rejoice not, O Israel, to exultation, like the peoples” (Hosea 9:1).  The Gemara asks: And let him send them a response from here: “They do not drink wine with a song; strong drink is bitter to them who drink it” (Isaiah 24:9), indicating that song is no longer allowed. The Gemara answers: If he had answered by citing that verse, I would say that this matter applies only to instrumental music, in accordance with the previous verse: “The mirth of tabrets ceases, the noise of them who rejoice ends, the joy of the harp ceases” (Isaiah 24:8); however, vocal song is permitted. Therefore, Mar Ukva teaches us that all types of song are forbidden.
This was later codified [Rambam, Hilchot Ta’aniyot 5:14; Shulchan Aruch in OH 560:3]

This was softened to allow song.  Sotah 48a: "Rav Huna nullified all types of song... Later, when Rav Ḥisda came and belittled this prohibition, people began to sing again."

But we can't mourn on Shabbat/Yom Tov!  So the prohibition against musical instruments on those days rests on the prohibition against "completing" an object on Shabbat [Eruvin 104a].  Playing an instrument "completes" it [Rambam, Hil’chot Shabbat 23:4; Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayyim 338:1].  Also, one might end up fixing (or tuning?) the musical instrument. [Mishna, Beitza 36b]

Comment: _We stopped using musical instruments in shul after the Temple was destroyed, as a sign of mourning._ Source? FWIW, although traditional synagogues do not utilize instruments in services, Carlebach minyanim do. (But I'd hardly call them traditional.)

Comment: @ezra I think Igeret Moshe among a number of other sources have debated the use of instruments during tefillah. Few Orthodox shuls use this regularly, and from what I've seen the Churban is not the real issue in most of the debate. It's mainly b/c of *chukat hagoyim*. And, even that's debatable.

Comment: This question is based on two hypotheses it provides no evidence for: that we used instruments in the synagogue before the destruction, and that we stopped thereafter. Well, I guess that's one: that there's a degree to which we used instruments before the destruction and stopped thereafter. The question is scarcely valid without support for that hypothesis. Please [edit] in such support.

Comment: @DanF Even synagogues before modern Christian worship (with organ, etc.) did not utilize musical instruments in services. I'm wondering if maybe (maybe!) the issur of using instruments on Shabbos make it impractical.

Comment: I think that @ezra probably has hit the nail on the head. "Major" services are those on Shabbat/Hag, when there is a problem with musical instruments that tuning them is forbidden. The only frequent time for musical addition would be weddings or britot, and it didn't catch on.

Comment: Music was only used in the Temple by Leviim and not used prayers in synagogues. I don't recall somebody mentions a musical instrument in a shul at the Rabbinical times.

Comment: Maybe it's worth asking the question without that assumption: Can we use instruments after the Temple is rebuilt?

Comment: @Epicentre and Chol Hamoed and Chanuka and Purim and Rosh Chodesh and ...

Comment: How do you know that they used instruments in Shul before the destruction? I’m unaware of a source that discusses using them at any point except when the Leviim sang on the duchan while the Karbanos were brought. Psalm 150 just says to praise him with these instruments, nothing about where the praising was done.

Comment: @AlBerko And if he asked it that way, the comments would still be upset at him for not providing motivation as to why he thinks it would be different...

Comment: @DonielF I +1ed the Q. Needs some improvement though.

Comment: I added some background.

Comment: See [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=210&st=&pgnum=84) where the author assumes that there was a custom in Prague’s Altneuschul to use musical instruments at Friday evening services, before the start of shabbat.

Comment: Where does Psalm 150 say anything about synagogues?

Comment: @Double AA -- Seven times a day I praise you (Psalms 119:164); 
My tongue shall speak of your... praise all day long. (Psalms 35:28)

Comment: @Maurice neither of those quotes are from Psalm 150 and neither discuss instruments.

Comment: You are supposed to praise God all the time (including the synagogue) and Ps 150 says to do it with musical instruments.